# Cannot edit or write anything in the activity_main.xml file in Android Stuio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I am not able to edit or write anything here.
I tried reopening android studio but it still didnt work.

code is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/pdTodoItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably working on an exemplary project. It will be sufficient to delete the .**idea** folder. Then open the project again.